# How do you exclude interaction term in r lm?

Tags: r, interaction, linearmodels

I'm working with a model from the Prestige dataset in the car package in R.

```
library(car)
library(carData)

data = na.omit(Prestige)
prestige = data$prestige
income = data$income
education = data$education
type = data$type
```

I'm trying to fit the model `lm(prestige ~ income + education + type + income:type + education:type)`.  For class I'm starting with the full model and working down to a smaller model, just backward selection.  One of the least useful covariates according to p-value is the `education:typeprof`. How do I just delete that covariate from the model without taking out all the education:type interactions? In general how do you exclude interactions with factors?  I saw an answer with the  `update` function specifying which interaction to exclude but it didn't work in my case.  Maybe I implemented it incorrectly.

```
fit4 = lm(prestige ~ income + education + type + income:type + education:type)
newfit = update(fit4, . ~ . - education:typeprof)
```

Unfortunately this didn't work for me.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what you want to do statistically, or why. could you clarify what you expect to gain? what the model will look like afterwards?

Comment: Yeah, I want to perform backward selection. Take out the covariate with highest p-value as I stated in the question. Once I take out the covariate with the highest p-value I will refit my model and then take out the covariate with the highest p-value in that model, so on and so forth until all the covariates are significant.  As it's specified to do it this way in my assignment.  The covariate with the highest p-value in the main model in the 'education:typeprof' covariate.  How do I drop just that one covariate?

Comment: So I want to fit the exact same model just without the `education:typeprof` covariate.

Comment: Do not use p-values for feature selection: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/291210/is-it-wrong-to-choose-features-based-on-p-value

Comment: I undestand this may not be the best, but I'm required to do it this way for my assignment

Comment: You're trying to remove an interaction term for just one level of the type variable, while leaving in the interaction term for another level. I'm not sure that's possible with the `update()` syntaxt. It might make more sense to look at `anova(fit4)` and the overall evidence for an education x type interaction, and then remove the entire `education:type` interaction if you think the evidence is too weak to support it.

Comment: Alright I'll definitely try that out.  Does it even make sense to keep leave out one interaction term and keep the others?

Comment: you might look into some more sophisticated methods for coalescing categorical variables. what your regression has suggested is there's no meaningful difference between the baseline level and the level type (so they can be coalesced). there are a few papers about factor agglomeration I've seen cited on cross validated

Answer (score 1):

So there is a way to drop a single interaction term.  Suppose you have the linear model

```
fullmodel = lm(y_sim ~ income + education + type + income:type + education:type - 1)
```

You can call `model.matrix` on `fullmodel` which will give you the X matrix for your linear model.  From there you can specify which column you'd like to drop and refit your model.

```
X = model.matrix(fullmodel)
drop = which(colnames(X) == 'education:typeprof')
X1 = X[,-1]
newfit = lm(presitge ~ X1 - 1)
```